# Conditional dropdown in smarty template

Tags: smarty

How to fetch data from database for one select box options according to the change in the selection of another select box. like country state selection. where when we select country, only the corresponding states will be shown.

Here are my Photos of code...
[my .tpl code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5biPk.jpg)
[my .php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjvaE.jpg)

Comment: You need javascript and maybe ajax for that

Comment: I know bt can u just show me one example??? I really need it.